# Automate Windows 8.1 Enterprise upgrade

Tags: automation, windows-8.1

I have been trying to find the necessary command line switches for automating the upgrade for my Windows 8  clients to Windows 8.1.  I have the ISO extracted and I've run setup.exe /? but that doesn't tell me enough.

I can't find any relevant information from search engines.  Can anyone point me to some documentation or information on how to automate the upgrade so that it keeps user data, programs, etc? I know how to do it when running the installer manually, but I obviously do not wish to do that with 100+ machines.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this is not the case with this.  Original installation of operating system is done through applying a wim file to a new machine.  This is an inplace upgrade that can only be accomplished by running the setup installer in a specific manner.  Two different beasties, unfortunately.

Comment: Related: [Update Windows 8 Enterprise to Windows 8.1 Enterprise KMS activation](http://superuser.com/questions/661517/update-windows-8-enterprise-to-windows-8-1-enterprise-kms-activation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to this link](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/springboard/archive/2013/07/30/start-your-windows-8-1-deployment-planning.aspx) you can run the command `setup.exe /auto:upgrade` to automatically upgrade to 8.1.